# Move In App Purchase items from one app to an other?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have an old app with in app purchase items. We are moving to a totally new app that will sell the same items while the old one will not be in use.
Can we move the items to the new app in iTunes connect?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. The IAP process is governed completely by Apple. You can probably set up a server generating promo codes for the users of the old app. And using the promo code unlocks the features in the new app?

Or some document type that could be sent via email and when your app opens it, unlocks the content.

You will need some mechanism to ensure these (either the promo code or the files) are used just once.